# Why does "sudo apt upgrade" install LibreOffice?

Tags: apt, system-installation, libreoffice

I've just installed a fresh Jammy Jellyfish, and I chose "minimal installation" during the install procedure - explicitly *without* LibreOffice. Now, running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` it starts installing LibreOffice. It's not a big deal, I can always remove it manually afterwards, but I'm sort of puzzled as to why it does this...?

Comment: Hm simulate this the next time please `apt -s -o APT::Get::Install-Recommends=false full-upgrade`